# 5.1 USB Headphones not recognized

Tags: 10.10, sound

I have a pair of 5.1 Bluetooth headphones that connect to any PC via bluetooth or USB. For some reason my Ubuntu 10.10 laptop won't read the headphones and won't even allow me to use them. The best it can do is charge them. Any commands or tips to get them working? Thanks in advance.

I'm connecting them via USB since my laptop doesn't use Bluetooth.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `lsusb` when they're plugged in? Without additional information - like the brand and model headphone - it's going to be very difficult to assist you.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, go to Main Menu, System, Preferences, Choose "Sound" choose the "Hardware" and "Output" tabs, see if the USB headphones (or similar) show up and are selected.

If so you will need to go to the preferences menu of the application you're trying to use and make sure the Audio Output is set to use the USB headphones instead of the default on board audio device.

Another possibility is that the device is muted, if so run "alsamixer" in a terminal and in the Alsamixer panel, press F6 to select the correct sound card (USB Speaker or similar) and make sure the volumes are not set too low and unmute them.

You might need to play around with these settings (as I had to also) to get them to work. Take note of what you change in case you need to change them back.